# How to get the values from plist in Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, plist, saxparser

Currently i am working in Android application, Using plist to store some values in Resource folder, then i get the local plist value from Resource in Android, but i cannot get these, How to parse local plist value in Android? 
please help me

Thanks

Here i mentioned Plist value here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Code</key>
        <string>11</string>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>Afghanistan</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Code</key>
        <string>12213</string>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>Aland Islands</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Code</key>
        <string>24144</string>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>Albania</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Code</key>
        <string>35223434</string>
        <key>Country</key>
        <string>Algeria</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: [Android PList Parser](https://github.com/tenaciousRas/android-plist-parser)

Example usage from the tests-

```
PListXMLParser parser = new PListXMLParser();
PListXMLHandler handler = new PListXMLHandler();
parser.setHandler(handler);
parser.parse(plistContentAsString);
PList plist = ((PListXMLHandler)parser.getHandler()).getPlist();
// use the plist
plist.getRootElement(); // get root element
```

Comment: Not helpful. No clear answer on how to use the mentioned library.